# Generate xcode .stringdict file from script

Tags: xcode, localization, plist, plistbuddy

I am trying to create a script (the language is not relevant, but it is a mix of node/js and bash) to **generate plural localization files** for xcode known as `.stringdict` format.

The Apple documentation as usual doesn't help (to be kind) and could only find help about the **format** in this [archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html).

The problem is that even just copying an existing valid file and re-creating it from shell, it apparently gets invalidated for not being in the correct format.
Trying to open it from Xcode results in the following error:

> Tried to create a document (class: IDEPlistDocument) and got a document with a different, non-conforming fileType back instead.

Reading around it appears that xcode "conveniently" converts the file to binary adding some metadata. I don't see the sense in this, but i tried anyway to open and re-save the file with **PlistBuddy** *(which in the while dear Apple has removed from standard path and for which there appear to be ZERO documentation around, despite being a long used official tool)*, something like:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "Print" .<project-root>/Resources/de.lproj/Localizable.stringsdict
```

with no success.

I have tried as well with plutil and again, no luck:

```
plutil -convert xml1 ./<project-root>/Resources/de.lproj/Localizable.stringsdict
```

**TLDR:**
How can i create a stringdict file that is readable by xcode from a script (in any language, using any library or tool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and

`plutil -convert binary1 Localizable.stringsdict`

helped me, it's not user readable but Xcode can open it.

But after a while i've realized that restarting Xcode also works after running `plutil -convert xml1 Localizable.stringsdict`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up leaving the script as is, the compiler apparently can handle it even if xcode cannot open it somehow. Accepting for the good will.